# Fill array if previous array is char on the same position

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

the description might be very confusing so an example will be better:

```
void fillKey (char **matrix, char **key, int length) {

   int k = 0;
   //fill key array until same num of chars
   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       //only fill at fields with alphab
       if ( isalpha(matrix[0][i]) != 0 ) {
           matrix[1][i] = key[1][k];
           k++;
           if ( k>= strlen(key[1]) )
               k = 0;
       }

   }

   printf("%s\n", matrix[0]);
   printf("%s\n", matrix[1]);
}
```

Input: `Hello world!` and key of `abc` the result should be:

`Hello world!`

`abcab cabca!`

However, the function stops working after any non-alpha char.

`Hello world!`

`abcab`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Solved, skipped array field will be `NULL` meaning I have to copy the non-alpha char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void fillKey (char **matrix, char **key, int length) {

   int k = 0;
   //fill key array until same num of chars
   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       //only fill at fields with alphab
       if ( isalpha(matrix[0][i]) != 0 ) {
           matrix[1][i] = key[1][k];
           k++;
           if ( k>= strlen(key[1]) )
               k = 0;
       }
       else
       {
           matrix[1][i] = matrix[0][i];
       }
   }

   printf("%s\n", matrix[0]);
   printf("%s\n", matrix[1]);
}
```

I have added the `else` part. Without that, `matrix[1][i]` for non alpha characters would be NULL and nothing would be written after that.

Answer (score 1):

If the second string is full of NULL characters, then when you skip copying the space, your printf will stop printing at the first NULL character, which corresponds to the first non-alpha char.

Comment: Ok, so `if(isalpha) {...} else { matrix[1][i] = matrix[0][i] }` will fix the problem...Damn, thank you very much!